# Is there a way to do what Chrome's reset "restore settings to their original defaults" more selectively?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome currently(as of 2023 though not sure when they put this option in), has an option in settings  "reset and cleanup".  And within that it has two options "restore settings to their original defaults", and "clean-up computer".

Is there a way to do what Chrome's reset "restore settings to their original defaults" does, but more selectively?

That could help in the case of a browser hijacker but the reset removes other things eg it logs me out of Google so presumably removes all cookies. And to the extent where not only does it not know / i.e. it  "forgets" the password but it doesn't even know/store the username anymore after the reset, so it's a total "log out".

I wonder if there is a more manual way of doing the "reset" that it does, that gives more control.

That'd help determine restoring which bit of the "reset" got rid of the browser hijacker, and it'd help in choosing which cookies if any get removed or kept. And it'd help in diagnosis generally, where there's some issue that a "browser reset" could help.

Answer (score 0):

There are methods to force some settings on Chrome, using registry updates
(no guarantee that this will work now or in the future).

The registry key is
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome`.

To get the list of all the possible registry items, download
[Chrome Browser bundle zip file](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9131254?hl=en).
Find the file
`.\Configuration\examples\chrome.reg`.

This file will contain the names of all the registry settings.
But I can't tell which ones do what, so some research is required.

Comment: hmm thing is that to remove the browse hijacker I had to click reset for each chrome profile.  I'm not sure how/if that translates to that reg file